# Force content to center of page with twitter bootstrap/rails view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a "navbar" on the left side of my page like so:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked span2">
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

My question is pretty general - How can I force this navbar to go all the way down the left side of my page without creating a thousand list items? Right now, my content starts where I want it too but after it exceeds the bottom of the navbar it starts placing content under the navbar. I want all content to be placed to the right of this navbar.

Comment: use class pull-right for ul to move it to right

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, you need to leverage the bootstrap grid to effect columns. Try this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked span2">
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9">
     //Main content which won't get floated under the nav
   </div>
</div>
```

ref: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid